# AngularJS: Apply a transclude directive only if it's child of another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parent, directive

I want to create a directive that is applied to `<tr>`, but only if it's inside a `<table parent-directive>`, not a simple `<table>`. I don't want to add a directive for each `<tr>` in my table for readability purposes.

```
app.directive('tr', function() {
    return {
        transclude: 'element',
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^parent-directive',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl, $transclude) {
            //things to do only if child of <table parent-directive>
        }
    }
};
```

Some problems here:

- If I use the `<tr>` in a normal `<table>` it throws an error.
- If I use the optional require `?^parent-directive`, I have a transclusion conflict on other `<tr>` with directive `ng-include`.

**Is there a way to apply a directive conditionnally?**

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to apply a directive conditionally AFAIK.

However there is another way to solve your problem, a sort of reversal: use the `compile` function of the `parentDirective` to add the child directive to all `<tr>` elements beneath it, e.g. as:

```
app.directive('parentDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function(tElem, tAttrs) {
            tElem.find('tr').attr('child-directive', '');
        }
    };
});
```

See a proof of concept [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1qL6go8g/). Note that the `child-directive` is automatically applied only to children of `<table parent-directive>`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I use `ng-repeat` on `<tr>`, so I can't use your solution. `<tr>` are async with the compilation of `<table>`.